# Is the two's complement always a signed number?

Tags: binary

Hey guys I just started taking a computer science class in high school and while doing and assignment, I got pretty confused with one thing.

I'm working with unsigned numbers and I want the two's complement of 234 (1110 1010) . First I convert it to a one's complement (0001 0101) then I add +1 to the one's complement therefore I should get (0001 0110). 
However, when I use an online calculator converter it gives me 0000000011101010.

Comment: Was that a typo, or did the calculator give you the original number for the two's complement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one of two misunderstandings:

2's complement is for representing *signed* numbers.  There is also no need to do any conversions for a positive 2's complement number.  So if your number is longer than 8-bits, there is padding in front of those 8-bits and your number is really `0000 0000 .... 1110 1010`, which is a *positive* 234. And the 2's complement of that positive number is itself (identity).

The 8-bit number `1110 1010` is not 234 (decimal) in 2's complement.  It is a negative 22 (the negative of the value `0001 0110` from the procedure you described).  Probably, your calculator is assuming the wrong number of bits for your data, and the sign bit (most-significant bit) is actually a padded 0.

The decimal number 234 is actually too large for 8-bit numbers since you have to devote one bit to the sign.  This means that 8-bit numbers must be between `-(2^7)` and `(2^7) -1` which in decimal are `-128` to `127`.